# How to set header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" in Springboot application?

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp, spring-boot

The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header `X-Content-Type-Options` was not set to 'nosniff'.

This allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type. Current (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Include spring security in your build (build.gradle)

   compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version:'2.1.4.RELEASE'

Or pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

ref: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.1.2.RELEASE

2. Add below java code.

   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;

   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

   ```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable();

       }
   }
   ```

**Before:**

```
Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 15 May 2019 19:05:00 GMT
X-Auth-Token →5178dc4e-eac5-40be-9ded-dcfa85c644b6
X-B3-Spanid →3d9a5b2fd21b075c
X-B3-Traceid →3d9a5b2fd21b075c
X-Vcap-Request-Id →4988b251-c2c5-4c5f-558b-ed6bce724e1f
Content-Length →992
```

**After:**

```
X-B3-TraceId →51e54c950ae24fa1
X-B3-SpanId →51e54c950ae24fa1
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma →no-cache
Expires →0
X-Frame-Options →DENY
x-auth-token →92195048-341d-48a7-93a6-f6f0446f3f0c
Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Date →Fri, 17 May 2019 15:50:59 GMT
```